# TextView overwrites new text on top of old, rather than replace it. (Kotlin - Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, settext

I have a textView that correctly makes this:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAbove"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LIMBER UP"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

[image: Screenshot]

However in my code where I want to change the text to something new, like this:

```
tvAbove.text = "HELLO453"
```

The new text just overwrites it, rather than deleting and replacing.

[image]

Please help me get the normal behaviour.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Here is the class for those who asked:

```
 class ExerciseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var restTimer: CountDownTimer?= null
    private var exerciseTimer: CountDownTimer?= null
    private var restProgress = 0
    private var exerciseProgress = 0


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise)

        //toolbar acts as action bar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar_exercise_activity)
        val actionbar = supportActionBar
        if(actionbar != null){
            actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        }
        toolbar_exercise_activity.setNavigationOnClickListener{
            onBackPressed()
        }



        setupRestView()
    }

    private fun setRestProgressBar(){
        progressBar.progress = restProgress
        restTimer = object : CountDownTimer(10000, 1000){
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                Log.i("onTick", "restProgress = ${restProgress.toString()}")
                restProgress++
                if(restProgress == 6){
                    tvAbove.text = ""
                    tvAbove.text = "HELLO543"
                }
                progressBar.progress = 10 - restProgress
                tvTimer.text = (10 - restProgress).toString()

                Log.i("tvTimer.text = ", tvTimer.text as String)
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(this@ExerciseActivity, "Now start the exercise", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }.start()
    }



    override fun onDestroy() {
        if(restTimer != null){
            restTimer!!.cancel()
            restProgress = 0

        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }
    private fun resetRestView(){
        if(restTimer != null){
            restTimer!!.cancel()
            restProgress = 0
        }
    }


    private fun setupRestView(){
        Log.i("msg", object{}.javaClass.enclosingMethod!!.name)
        resetRestView()
        setRestProgressBar()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this TextView contained in a custom View class? Looks like the frame buffer isn't getting cleared before drawing, but that is usually all handled internally to Android's view system.

Comment: I don't think so, it's just a standard textView. How would I know if I've made it custom?

Comment: You would know if you did. But I'm talking about the view that contains it, not TextView itself.

Comment: Have you modified anything about the activity in the manifest, like changing the hardware rendering setting?

Comment: No, I've added this:

       <activity android:name=".ExerciseActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"></activity>

Comment: Regarding the views, I don't think I've made a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, could you share your Kotlin class?, the first solution I'd suggest is to "clean" the text and then put your text:

```
tvAbove.text = ""
tvAbove.text = "Hello453"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think your suggestion isn't deleting any text with the "", it's just writing nothing over the top of the text like before.

Is there a good way to share a big block of code? I'm not allowed to edit the question and put in my class.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything preventing you from editing your own question.

Comment: @LiamBaron I tried your code and for me everything works fine.

Comment: @akhil Nair. Thanks for trying that, useful to know it's my machine.

Answer (score 0):

This happened in my case because the TextView had a transparent background and so did the parent view.

1. Setting a background that is not transparent to the TextView or the parent View will solve this.
2. But in my case I wanted the transparent background, so I had to define a CustomTextView and did override the onDraw method.

NB: The width and height of the TextView has to be fixed and not variable else, if old width or height is greater than the new one the problem will persist.

Sample code in Java

```
public class TransparentTextView extends TextView{
    public TransparentTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TransparentTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TransparentTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```